# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (libgdx)

Tags: java, android, frameworks, libgdx

Been trying to work with the Libgdx framework and have been experiencing some frustrating issues.. I'm following a tutorial and I'm unable to run my project. What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.mygdx.game.android;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class AndroidLauncher implements ApplicationListener {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture mario;


    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        mario = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("mario.png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);


        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(mario, 50, 50);
        batch.end();



    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Here's what the console displays when I run the project:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/jnigen/NativeCodeGenerator
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild.main(GdxBuild.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Are you trying to build and run it on Android?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but realised that I was running GdxBuild instead. Ensure that you right click on DesktopLauncher.java > Run As > Java Application.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was my first **libGDX** project, I was running it using **Android Studio version 3.0.1** on KUBUNTU, and as soon as I imported the freshly created project using **gdx-setup.jar (Setup App)** to Android Studio a popup message was asking informing me to update **Gradle** which I did, and that broke the project.

[image]

**Solution:**
create a new libGDX project and import it **without** updating Gradle (click "**Don't remind me again for this project**") and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Rigth click project- properties - build options - order and export and check all gdx libraries. Thats probably it, that error comes when it cant find a class at runtime.

Comment: Unfortuantely this wasn't the issue. Already tried this and It didn't resolve anything (the library was already checked). Although, I only have one gdx library (my-gdx-game-core [Builder]) avaliable to check.. is that normal?

Comment: the error suggest that it can't find a class , did follow some tutorial for this , if so provide a link i can look at it

Comment: Yes I followed a tutorial to set up gradle and libgdx and after importing the test projects (my-gdx-game-android) etc.. everything seemed to work fine. It's when I got to this point I started experiencing the issues https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjbBr7W8ZvU&index=4&list=PLvnXjBkwUhDHHUDTkV42GscJHf3BplZtN

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the only way I could reproduce it was by using a desktop configuration. So instead of using a desktop configuration, run it as a gradle config. In the command line, that would be:

```
gradlew desktop:run
```

Since it's a pain manually doing that every single time you want to run the project, create a new Gradle run configuration

[image: Press the plus icon and select "Gradle"]

If you pick the Gradle project in the run config to be the sub module, all you need to type as the task is `gradlew run` instead of `gradlew desktop:run`.

You have to define the memory flags in the VM option input (does not have to have these values though):

```
-Xmx2G -Xms128M
```

Script parameters can remain empty. Note that this entire thing counts as a Gradle build, so you have to kill the process (if it's running) before you can launch a new one.

I can export a jar without problems, so you should be fine in production.

**TL:DR;** Use a Gradle run config with `gradlew desktop:run` instead of using an application

Answer (score 2):

So many different answers. Rather than follow them all I created a new project. As simply as possible; if upgrading IntelliJ will break my project I'll want less unused features to drag into 2018.

I was getting

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener
...`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener
...`

After upgrading IntelliJ from 2017.3 to 2018.1.

This time I didn't tick any boxes with:

[image: simplest libgdx setup]

and similarly for the "Advanced" settings:

[image: simplest advanced settings]

Without IDEA selected the project took 10s to generate and gave different instructions on how to import which met with markedly more success (The old ways are the best remembered, Eclipse anyone?).

Of course I got a few more errors but nothing I hadn't overcome before in getting a new project off the ground. After that it's just a matter of copying the old files over. One more hint, no matter what settings IntelliJ offers to open to set your Java level to 1.7, the Gradle files don't get touched and so you must hunt the remaining 1.6 references manually.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click -> Run As -> Run Configurations -> Click Desktop-Launcher in the menu on the left and then click run, this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Project structure -> modules -> choose required module (desktop, android, etc) -> Dependencies -> Add Library.

Don't forget change Scope from "Provided" to "Compile".