# Don't understand a libGDX error

Tags: java, libgdx

I started a new libGDX project, copied all the relevant code from the previous project, but am now getting a strange error I dont understand:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/jnigen/NativeCodeGenerator
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild.main(GdxBuild.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I can't even render a simple window.
Hopefully someone can explain to me, what this error means.

Cheers, Joshflux

Comment: Check your run configuration. It looks like you're running the GdxBuild class of libgdx instead of your projects desktop launcher.

Comment: As is mentiond [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080731/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-libgdx), make sure you right-click on the DesktopLauncher.java and Run As -> Java Application.  You CAN take care of that through the run configurations.

Comment: Thanks guys, that helped a lot. Problem solved.